# Can a Bottling Bucket explode?

Tags: fermentation

For some random reasons, I had to siphon my beer from a carboy to my bottling bucket, which doesn't have airlock or something in the lid. The fermentation was already done, so what I understand I can't have CO2 problems, or could I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the beer has finished fermenting, you do not need to be concerned with your bucket exploding.

Also, any pressure developed in the bucket from fermentation would blow the lid off before actually exploding.

Comment: True -- the lid would come off. And then a lot beer would come gushing out. But, as you say, only if the beer is actively fermenting.